# How can I deploy a kubernetes replica pods with different spring profiles

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have spring boot application and deployed in kubernetes with 4 replica pods configurations. Now I have spring profiles: `api` and `scheduler`. When `api` spring profile is active then only pods will run those apis and when `scheduler` profile is active the pods will run the scheduler code.
Now I want 2 of my pods to run with `api` and other 2 pods with `scheduler` spring profile. How can I achieve that in kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to define two pod yaml and override the docker file CMD and entrypoint.  Yaml file 'command and args' will override whatever mention in docker's Entrypoint.

For api container

```
  spec:
  containers:
   - name: api-container
     image: nameOfImage
     command: ["java"]
     args: ["-jar", "application.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=api"]
```

Similarly you can define for scheduler container.